# Displaying url in php search box

Tags: php, html, web

I am trying to make this search page to display the URL's below the search bar instead of the actual name of the "product". Here is how far I've gone and I'm currently stuck. I've also created a main html page which just servers for the search box. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
    ************************************************/

// Credentials
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "tutorial";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";

//  Connection
global $tutorial_db;
$tutorial_db = new mysqli();
$tutorial_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$tutorial_db->set_charset("utf8");

//  Check Connection
if ($tutorial_db->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $tutorial_db->connect_error);
exit();
}

/************************************************
 Search Functionality
************************************************/

// Define Output HTML Formating
 $html = '';
 $html .= '<li class="result">';
 $html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
 $html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
 $html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
 $html .= '</a>';
 $html .= '</li>';

 // Get Search
 $search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9@]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
 $search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

 // Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
  // Build Query
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM search WHERE function LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

// Do Search
$result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $result_array[] = $results;
}

// Check If We Have Results
if (isset($result_array)) {
    foreach ($result_array as $result) {

        // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
        $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['function']);
        $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['name']);
        $display_url = 'http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern='.urlencode($result['function']).'&lang=en';

        // Insert Name
        $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

        // Insert Function
        $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);

        // Insert URL
        $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);

        // Output
        echo($output, $display url);
    }
}else{

    // Format No Results Output
    $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
    $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No Results Found.</b>', $output);
    $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

    // Output
    echo($output);
}
}
```

I've tried displaying it in "if statement" but it's still not showing properly:

```
   if (isset($result_array)) {
    foreach ($result_array as $result) {

        // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
        $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['function']);
        $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['name']);
        $display_url = 'http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern='.urlencode($result['function']).'&lang=en';

        // Insert Name
        $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

        // Insert Function
        $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);

        // Insert URL
        $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);

        // Output
        echo($output, $display url);
    }
```

Here is the image where the url is supposed to come out and how search page looks like:

[image]

Comment: I can see this line have issue "echo($output, $display url);' change it to "echo $output, $display_url;". BTW what is exact issue?

Comment: Yes this line has an issue and the edit you've said doesn't solve the problem. The issue is that my search page only displays the name of the product not the URL as I am trying to do.

Comment: can you print your $result_array, also if possible attach screenshot of your search page so that we will have visibility of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
$html = '';
 $html .= '<li class="result">';
 $html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
 $html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
 $html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
 $html .= '</a>urlString2';
 $html .= '</li>';
```

remove :

```
echo $output, $display_url;
```

and add in place of above:

```
$output = str_replace('urlString2', $display_url, $output);
echo $output;
```